# Will Firestore be able to handle 50000 daily read or writes and keep performance optimal?

Tags: database, performance, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Let's say my app will grow into 50,000 daily read/writes, will Firestore database be able to handle that operation with optimal performance? I am building a React-Native app and this is my first time using non-SQL DB.

Answer (score 1):

The limits of Cloud Firestore are quite well documented in the page on [usage and limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas). Reading/writing 50,000 documents per day won't be a performance issue, but I highly recommend you study that page carefully, and then do some experimentation with the API to see how it behaves for your app.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions.  I was trying to search for how to retrieve a limited amount of data on the user`s request from Firestore but was not able to find something relevant. Are you able to help me in this aspect? I only found something like: you could query for the first 3 cities alphabetically with citiesRef.orderBy("name").limit(3) . But I would like to fetch on request, so, for example, fetch 10 next ones when a user requests. How can I fetch NEXT items?

Comment: That is called pagination, and this should be a good starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D+pagination

Comment: thanks Frank, sadly there is no documentation for pagination with React Native. Or at least i couldnt find any.

Comment: Pagination is the same for all JavaScript clients, and very similar across all Firebase SDKs.

Comment: hey Frank, I have tried searching for pagination with real-time-fetching using onSnapshot() listener but couldnt find anythign related to it. Please, if you know how to implement it just check my latest post where I have asked a question about this and give a suggestion.